# Excel 2013 formula throws #Value! error with SAP BusinessObjects Dashboard

Tags: excel-formula, dashboard, business-objects, xcelsius

I am using this Excel formula

```
=IF(C92=0,D102,D101)
```

It is throwing a `#Value!` error for my SAP BusinessObjects Dashboard 4.1 (SP7).

Is there another way to write this formula?

My guess is that SAP does not like using zero for `C92=0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities as to the cause of the error but most will be loosely based upon the fact that you are trying to compare a numerical zero to a cell containing a text string or a blank cell. The cell may even contain a zero as text (e.g. `="0"`); a numerical **0** is not the same thing as text-that-looks-like-a-zero.

If you use the [VALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VALUE-function-257D0108-07DC-437D-AE1C-BC2D3953D8C2) and wrap some error control around it to accommodate cases when numerical conversion is impossible then you should get consistent results.

```
=IF(IFERROR(VALUE(C92), 0)=0, D102, D101)
```

The [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) is used to provide a zero when numerical conversion is not possible. This is my 'best guess' at what you want to occur. Another scenario would be to provide an outside result if not conversion is possible.

```
=IFERROR(IF(VALUE(C92)=0, D102, D101), "something else")
```

There are a number of other possibilities. If you have trouble getting the results you expect, please edit your question to include more detail on what outcome(s) you would expect for different case scenarios.